# kext: waiting for thread exit before kextunload

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, kernel-extension

This has been asked a few times over the years, and I'm just checking in if there is an acceptable solution yet.

As for the thread termination, we use standard Unix way that we inherited from Solaris via ZFS. So the threads have mutex, and condvar, and finish with:

```
    l2arc_thread_exit = 0;
    cv_broadcast(&l2arc_feed_thr_cv);
    thread_exit();
 }
```

and the main thread waits with;

```
    mutex_enter(&l2arc_feed_thr_lock);
    cv_signal(&l2arc_feed_thr_cv);  /* kick thread out of startup */
    l2arc_thread_exit = 1;
    while (l2arc_thread_exit != 0)
        cv_wait(&l2arc_feed_thr_cv, &l2arc_feed_thr_lock);
    mutex_exit(&l2arc_feed_thr_lock);
```

Fairly straight forward, however, the problem is between the exiting thread signaling parent, and actually getting to the end of `thread_exit()`, and, the parent thread finishing and XNU cleans up kextunload by releasing all memory.

Sure it is rare, but it can happen. It is easy to highlight by adding a delay just before the `thread_exit()` call.

Yes I could put a delay in before main thread completes, so kextunload has a bigger chance to run after threads are gone, but ultimately, it would be nice to be able to ensure the thread has actually gone away.

Internet has suggested things like calling `thread_suspend()` and `thread_resume()` until either returns KERN_TERMINATED. But APPLE is a bit mean with what we can actually call, and we can't link against those calls. (Well, I could, but it would be nicer not to have a sleep-loop, but a wakeup)

So, has there been any clever ways to handle this synchronization? Apple legal way? Non-apple legal way?

Comment: Thought I would at least try the two desperation methods, first we force link against `thread_resume()` so we can keep calling it until it returns `KERN_TERMINATED`. but alas, the first thing it does is call `thread_mtx_lock();` so we end up with "trying to interlock destroyed mutex" panic.

We tried to reverse the logic, have thread not call `thread_terminate()` but spin, and "parent" to call `thread_terminate(thread)` instead, as it calls `thread_wait()` if current!=self. Alas, it fails due to `if (thread->task == kernel_task) return KERN_FAILURE.

Delay before exit, anyone?

Comment: A simple 
` while(get_bsdthread_info(thread) != NULL) 
  delay(hz>>2);
`
will technically work, in that `get_bsd_thread_info()` will return the uthread structure ptr, which is freed and set to NULL in `thread_terminate()`.

However, kext developers are technically not allowed to call `get_bsdthread_info()` so it isn't a great solution (without even going into the delay polling)

Comment: I asked Apple about it and they replied with "
The kernel team is investigating your question. They say you've raised a valid point." So I will wait and see what they recommend.

Comment: So HighSierra kernel added `boolean_t thread_is_active(thread_t thread)` which was encouraging, only to find it is also private-export, and we are 'not allowed' to call it. So close.